# ionic datepicker bower component error

Tags: ionic-framework

tryin to implement the ionic datepicker ,by rajesh this is the controller implementation ,after the dependency injection

```
.controller('PostCtrl', function ($scope, partyStore, $rootScope, $ionicPopup, $location) {
    $scope.currentDate = new Date();
    $scope.title = "Custom Title";

    $scope.datePickerCallback = function (val) {
        if (typeof (val) === 'undefined') {
            console.log('Date not selected');
        } else {
            console.log('Selected date is : ', val);
        }
    };
```

this is template for rendering the view ,

```
<ionic-datepicker idate="currentDate" disablepreviousdates="true" disablefuturedates="false" callback="datePickerCallback"
        title="title">
            <button class="button button-block button-positive">{{ currentDate | date:'dd - MMMM - yyyy' }}</button>
        </ionic-datepicker>
```

this is the error it generates

```
TypeError: a.callback is not a function
at link.n.on.e.show.buttons.onTap (ionic-datepicker.js:1)
at Scope.IonicModule.factory.extend.$buttonTapped (ionic.bundle.js:45347)
at $parseFunctionCall (ionic.bundle.js:21044)
at ionic.bundle.js:53458
at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:23100)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:23199)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.js:53457)
at HTMLButtonElement.eventHandler (ionic.bundle.js:11713)
at triggerMouseEvent (ionic.bundle.js:2863)
at tapClick (ionic.bundle.js:2852)
```

Comment: Can u show me your HTML code?

Answer (score 3):

You are not doing properly, have you followed the steps to follow?

2) Give the path of ionic-datepicker.bundle.min.js in your index.html file.

```
<!-- path to ionic/angularjs -->
<script src="lib/ionic-datepicker/dist/ionic-datepicker.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

3) In your application module inject the dependency ionic-datepicker, in order to work with the ionic time picker

```
angular.module('mainModuleName', ['ionic', 'ionic-datepicker']){
//
}
```

4) Use the below format in your template's corresponding controller

```
$scope.datepickerObject = {
  titleLabel: 'Title',  //Optional
  todayLabel: 'Today',  //Optional
  closeLabel: 'Close',  //Optional
  setLabel: 'Set',  //Optional
  setButtonType : 'button-assertive',  //Optional
  todayButtonType : 'button-assertive',  //Optional
  closeButtonType : 'button-assertive',  //Optional
  inputDate: new Date(),  //Optional
  mondayFirst: true,  //Optional
  templateType: 'popup', //Optional
  showTodayButton: 'true', //Optional
  modalHeaderColor: 'bar-positive', //Optional
  modalFooterColor: 'bar-positive', //Optional
  from: new Date(2012, 8, 2), //Optional
  to: new Date(2018, 8, 25),  //Optional
  callback: function (val) {  //Mandatory
    datePickerCallback(val);
  },
  dateFormat: 'dd-MM-yyyy', //Optional
  closeOnSelect: false, //Optional
};

var datePickerCallback = function (val) {
  if (typeof(val) === 'undefined') {
    console.log('No date selected');
  } else {
    console.log('Selected date is : ', val)
  }
};
```

5) Then use the below format in your template / html file

```
<ionic-datepicker input-obj="datepickerObject">
  <button class="button button-block button-positive"> {{datepickerObject.inputDate | date:datepickerObject.dateFormat}}</button>
</ionic-datepicker>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use this

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/datePicker/

(here to get start with ngCordova : http://ngcordova.com/docs/install/ )

Really easy to use

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaDatePicker) {

var options = {
    date: new Date(),
    mode: 'date', // or 'time'
    minDate: new Date() - 10000,
    allowOldDates: true,
    allowFutureDates: false,
    doneButtonLabel: 'DONE',
    doneButtonColor: '#F2F3F4',
    cancelButtonLabel: 'CANCEL',
    cancelButtonColor: '#000000'
  };

  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

    $cordovaDatePicker.show(options).then(function(date){
        alert(date);
    });

  }, false);
});
```